# How can I get the index/event of a class when I have multiple instances of that class?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, indexing

I have a class that creates a `Label` and display text.
I also have a `Click` event that when it fires, the `Label` text changes.

I have another class, that passes a method to the first one that shows a `MessageBox`.
In the main `Form` I'm running a `for` loop that creates 2 instances of the class at random locations.

The problem is, when I click a `Label`, the text doesn't change on the `Label` that I want. It changes to the first `Label` (class) created.

How can I change that?

```
class J1
{
    public Label texto;
    public static int a = 0;

    //Calls the Method that Creates the Label
    public void Spawn(Form form, int _X, int _Y)
    {
        LL(form, _X, _Y);
    }

    //Creates the label
    public void LL(Form form, int _X, int _Y) 
    {
        texto = new Label()
        {
            Size = new System.Drawing.Size(35, 50),
            Left = _X,
            Top = _Y,
            Text = "nova label"
        };
        texto.Click += new EventHandler(Label_Clicada);
        form.Controls.Add(texto);
    }

    void Label_Clicada(object sender, EventArgs e) //Click event when fires
    {
        J2.M(); //2nd Class that shows a MessageBox
        //Changes Text, but doenst change the one that was clicked on
        texto.Text = texto.GetType().ToString(); 
    }
}
```

2nd Class(J2):

```
class J2
{
    public static void M()//Method that I pass to 1nd class(J1)
    {
        J1.a++;
        MessageBox.Show(J1.a.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: use `(sender as Label).Text = ...` in click event

Comment: Thanks man, worked like a charm! Can you explain me what the sender does in this case? Why it worked in my code?

Comment: `sender` is the object that generated the event. A `Label`, in this case. You can then *cast* (consider/look at the object) as a Label. Since `sender` is actually  a `Label`, you can then access it's properties. You could also cast it to `Control`: `(sender as Control).Text`, because [Label](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label) inherits from [Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control), which provides the `.Text` property (in `System.Windows.Forms.Control`).

Comment: This implies that `sender` could also be a `Button` or a `TextBox`. All derive from Control. This can be useful when you have to handle a single event for different Controls which have a common (meaningful) property. A `PictureBox` also derives from Control and has a `Click` event, but the `Text` property is not meaningful for that Control. If fact, it's hidden. But if you set: `pictureBox1.Text = "SomeString";`, it will be accepted event though the property is not listed. It won't produce any effect, though, because it's not a meaningful property for that Control (is not applied).

Answer (score 0):

As i posted in comment solution for this was using `(sender as Label).Text` in click event.

`sender` is type of `object` which contains `object` which fired event.

If we take a look at how events are fired with this code:

```
EventHandler<ThresholdReachedEventArgs> handler = ThresholdReached;
if (handler != null)
{
    handler(this, e);
}
```

We can see that `hanlder(this, e);` is passing `this` object which fires it and `e` as some parameters (event args).

Now `this / object` that passed event could be any object if you bind multiple objects to same event.

For example if you do `yourButton.Click += ClickEvent;` and `yourLabel.Click += ClickEvent` both buttons inside have code above but both of them will pass different `this (themselves)` and `e (events if there are any)`

so inside our event we can do this:

```
private void ClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(sender is Label)
    {
        Label l = sender as Label;
        //Do anything with label
    }
    else if(sender is Button)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        //Do anything with button
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unknown component");
        //Or
        throw new Exception("Unknown component");
    }
}
```